# Notepad++ weird red background

Tags: notepad++

I have notepad++ 8.1.9.2 and I got this weird yellow font on red background on some pseudo element selector

[image]

Comment: It depends on the language you have chosen and the style configurator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that notepad++ now include a `UNKNOW PSEUDOCLASS` chart in the Settings>Style Configurator>Css

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have selected json in languages as Toto said.(sorry can't comment)
In any case you can try going to Language-> None(normal text).

Answer (score 1):

It shows errors in red background. You can change the colour in menubar -> Settings -> Style Configurator -> select your language then select Style: Error, change Background colour.

For example if you open this text as json:

```
{
thereisNoBracesEndOftheDocument
525221
```

it is shown like that:

[image]

Because json format is incorrect. In addition, if your text has characters which cannot be encoded in select encode set, it is shown in red line.
For example I had this file:
[image]

Everything looks fine but problem is spaces are not really space charaters. I opened the document with hex editor:
[image]

You can see chracters: Â. It doesn't show properly in my text.